# My Developer Facebook app still got deactivated although I already completed Data Protection Assessment

Tags: facebook, authentication

My developer facebook app got deactivated 1 month ago because I missed the deadline of annual Data Protection Assessment. Then, I spent 2 days to complete this accessment and Facebook already informed me that my answers were reviewed and completed.
[Data Protection Assessment complete notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSOJt.png)

[Data Protection Assessment Status Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMOl3.png)
But when I tried to use Facebook login feature, I still got the error message:
[Facebook Login Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD4Be.png)

Is there anyone know why I got this problem?

Thanks.

I already completed the Data Protection Assessment and it is successful.

Comment: I'm having trouble passing the test. I'm being asked to provide evidence of a hacking test. How do you test your applications and systems for vulnerabilities and security issues? Do you have any advice? Please  5 days left...